# RSPEC testing shortest string in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I know I can do it in hash method, but I just don't understand why my method doesn't go through the "shuffle example"

This is the error I got.

```
1) shortest_string returns the shortest string regardless of ordering                                                                                              
     Failure/Error: expect(shortest_string(array)).to eq 'a'                                                                                                         

   expected: "a"                                                                                                                                                 
        got: "aaa"                                                                                                                                               

   (compared using ==)                                       

# ./shortest-string-spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

my_solution.rb

```
def shortest_string(arr)
  if arr.empty?
    nil
  else
    min_length = arr[0].length
    result = arr[0]
    arr.each do |element|
      element.length < min_length ? (result = element) : result
    end
    result
  end 
end
```

RSPEC

```
require_relative "my_solution"

describe 'shortest_string' do
  it "returns nil when the array is empty ([])" do
    expect(shortest_string([])).to be_nil
  end

  it "returns '' when that is the only element in the array" do
    expect(shortest_string([''])).to eq ''
  end

  it "returns 'cat' when that is the only element in the array" do
    expect(shortest_string(['cat'])).to eq 'cat'
  end

  it "returns the 'zzzzzzz' with the example array" do
    expect(shortest_string(['cat', 'zzzzzzz', 'apples'])).to eq 'cat'
  end

  it "returns the shortest string regardless of ordering" do
    # This creates an array containing ['a', 'aa', ...]
    # up to 10 characters long, but randomly ordered
    array = Array.new(10) { |i| 'a' * (i + 1) }.shuffle

    expect(shortest_string(array)).to eq 'a'
  end
end
```

UPDATE,

how can I do it in this way?

element.length < min_length ? (result = element) : result ? (min_length = element.length) ? min_length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting `min_length` when you find a new lowest so it still thinks that **anything** less than `arr[0].length` should pass through.

Example:

```
array = ["aaa", "a", "aa"]
```

the second and third element of that array are less than `min_length` and since you set `result = element` it captures the `aa` on the final pass through of the `each` method.

You can fix this by doing:

```
def shortest_string(arr)
  if arr.empty?
    nil
  else
    min_length = arr[0].length
    result = arr[0]
    arr.each do |element|
      if element.length < min_length 
        result = element
        min_length = element.length
      end
    end
    result
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)

```
array = ["aaa", "a", "aa"]
array.max_by { |x| -x.length }
# => "a" 

[].max_by { |x| -x.length }
# => nil
```